# Classpath root pointing to grails-app/views - how to amend?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, grails, resources, classpath

My goal is to add some Json files as project resources accessible from the code. The solution must work in IntelliJ and deployed in a Tomcat. I don't mind if the files are located under `grails-app/conf` or `src`.

Getting my classpath root using one of

- `grailsApplication.parentContext.getResource("classpath:")` or
- `grailsApplication.parentContext.getResource("classpath:.")`

resolves in `$MY_APP/grails-app/views`

However, trying to navigate from this root to `grails-app/src` using

- `grailsApplication.parentContext.getResource("classpath:..")`

results in: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [..] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist". This might be acceptable since a root is a root, I guess.

1. How can I extend my classpath to folders outside of `grails-app/views`?
2. How can I make sure that the solution works in both, IntelliJ and Tomcat deployment?

I'm using Gradle 3.5, Grails 3.3.11, Groovy 2.4.10. I'm working in IntelliJ. Rebuilding the project using the Gradle view has not helped so far. The project setup consists of

- grails-app/conf/application.yml
- grails-app/conf/application.groovy
- grails-app/conf/ApplicationResources.groovy (I've tried to add a resource entry here and rebuild the project)
- ... (Please feel free to have a look in [the project](https://github.com/openlibraryenvironment/gokb/tree/g3_master/server/gokbg3/) in case of further config detail questions.)

I've been exploring endless questions and answers of similar "how can I add my file to the classpath" questions, but nothing has helped so far.

Comment: You really should not use `grails-app/views/` for this.  You should use `src/main/resources/` and standard resource loading techniques.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Thanks - I would love to! How can I set this up? (I haven't set up the project.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PuneetBehl's answer helped me realizing that it isn't about the project code configuration. It is about the configuration of my IDE, which is IntelliJ. You can set Project Structure... --> Project Settings --> Modules. There, "Resource Folders" on the right hand side was listing as: "conf", "i18n" and "views". I dont know why IntelliJ chose "views" for the path `"/."`.

Anyway, it was enough to:

- use Puneet's proposed syntax: `getClass().getResource("/myfolder/example.json")`
- after I had created grails-app/conf/myfolder/example.json

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned earlier in the comment, that you should put the JSON files under `/src/main/resources` folder. And, you should be able to access the files as:

```
getClass().getResource("/example.json")
```

Here is an [example application](https://github.com/puneetbehl/grails-access-local-resource)

Comment: Thx very much for your efforts!! There isn't any configuration difference compared to the project that I've linked above. Which made me think. More. :-) And your answer helped me realizing that it must be the configuration of IDEA IntelliJ that I'm using.